# Fetch local path from current file in vim

Tags: windows, vim

My file is in a remote directory. When I get the name of the file using `%` in Vim, as described [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Get_the_name_of_the_current_file). I obtain a remote path, e.g. `\\domain\path\anotherpath\`. A certain command which I use, `!<command> %`, cannot cope with this remote path.

In a different program and in Windows explorer I see that the local path is `G:\path\anotherpath`

Now how can I fetch this local path in Vim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options, if your shellslash is always left alone on windows,

```
exe '!dir '.shellescape(expand('%:p'))

!dir "%"    " may also work
```

Should do it.

However, if your shellslash option has been modified, you'll have to be sure it's set to `noshellslash` on windows, or use `lh#system#FixPathName()` which comes from my [system-tools plugin](https://github.com/LucHermitte/vim-system-tools)

```
exe '!dir '.lh#system#FixPathName(expand('%:p'))
```

Note: and if you want to apply your command on the repertory where the current file is, `expand()` modifier will require a `:h` -> `expand('%:p:h')`.